# Failed to build Android project at the first run

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, aapt2

Just after I created a new project in Android Studio, it builds the app and gave this error. Java compiler error:

[image: Java compiler error]

And this Run tasks error:

[image: Run tasks error]

And I can not find where the log is.
I use the embedded JDK.
And when I switch to the JDK-10 that I installed, JDK10:

[image: JDK10]

I uninstall, and reinstall Android studio, but it doesn't work.
I've already set `%JAVA_HOME%` to JDK-10... I have no idea at all.

Answer (score 0):

As for the JDK issue, try with JDK 9 and follow the guide on [setting the JAVA_HOME variable on Windows](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html) - make sure it points to the directory not the executable.

As for the AAPT2 issue, to find the build log press the icon on the left hand side of the Build window - the one directly under the green hammer icon. It toggles the view from the list with round icons to the actual full log. The AAPT2 error and the reason for the failure should be in there. Failures during the resource merge usually mean there's a typo in your resource files or a PNG file is corrupted.

Comment: Did you try using jdk 9?

Comment: I have latest .jdk because i downloaded it 2 days before when i setting up android studio on my system.

Comment: Please try the embedded JDK again. It should be good enough and then we can work on fixing the AAPT2 issue.

Comment: but i did't get any of this `'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.` type error, i checked it now.

Comment: The first and second screenshots you posted show an error from aapt2 that you got during mergeDebugResources task.

Comment: Try doing whatever you did to get what you have in the fist screen shot.

Answer (score -1):

If you are experiencing issues while using `AAPT2`, you can disable it by setting `android.enableAapt2=false` in your `gradle.properties` file.

Hope it will works

Comment: It works, at least, I can run it. But there is another warning come out."The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore." I wonder if there any solution can solve this perfectly?

Comment: This is a warning and It will be removed at the end of 2018, so it's not a mejor issue , project works fine in this case.

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: I'd say it rather is an issue, because this is not a fix, you're just postponing the problem. You will have to fix your source at some point, and it is better to do it earlier rather than later.

Comment: this is not an issues it will be remved like google changing complie to implemention.

Comment: I added an answer, please let me know once you have found the build log and I'll help you find the solution. :)

Comment: @SandeepParish yeah and once the flag is removed then you will not be able to use AAPT1, you will have to use AAPT2 and then you will have to fix the issue with the resources. Using the flag is just postponing it.